# пояснение или вставка?

Tags: вставка

1.При этом, как отмечается, они, будучи гражданами Франции - один пакистанского, второй алжирского происхождения, использовали фальшивые сирийские паспорта, чтобы выдать себя за беженцев.

2. При этом, как отмечается, они, будучи гражданами Франции - один пакистанского, второй алжирского происхождения, - использовали фальшивые сирийские паспорта, чтобы выдать себя за беженцев.
3. При этом, как отмечается, они, будучи гражданами Франции, - один пакистанского, второй алжирского происхождения - использовали фальшивые сирийские паспорта, чтобы выдать себя за беженцев.

В первом предложении *один пакистанского, второй алжирского происхождения* - это пояснение слов *граждане Франции* и входит в деепричастный оборот?

Во втором и третьем - вставка? Тогда где нужно ставить запятую: до первого тире или до второго?

Answer (score 3):

Возможно оформить и как пояснительную, и как вставную конструкцию:

1.При этом, как отмечается, они, будучи гражданами Франции - один пакистанского, второй алжирского происхождения, использовали фальшивые сирийские паспорта, чтобы выдать себя за беженцев.-пояснение входит в оборот.

2.При этом, как отмечается, они, будучи гражданами Франции - один пакистанского, второй алжирского происхождения,- использовали фальшивые сирийские паспорта,  чтобы выдать себя за беженцев.-запятая всегда ставится ДО тире.